# Chinese character gets scrambled when going from JSP to server in Java

Tags: java, jsp, utf-8

I have already set

```
<%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

This in my JSP. But, after doing as

```
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("SEARCH_TEXT", srctxt);
```

or
passing as a parameter in the AJAX url,
I am still getting Chinese words as scrambled letters or '????' marks.
Required some insight regarding this. Please help.

Comment: Are you using JavaScript's [encodeURIComponent](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeURIComponent.asp)?

Comment: No, I guess. I do not have any idea regarding this.

Comment: @Mena, After your comment, I checked the 'encodeURIComponent' and as I encoded the Chinese string and decoded it my server side code, it got resolved. Thanx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Mena, After your comment, I checked the 'encodeURIComponent' and as I encoded the Chinese string and decoded it my server side code, it got resolved. Thanx. Pasting code for reference, 
**Client Side code,**

```
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("SEARCH_TEXT", encodeURIComponent(srctxt));
```

**Server Side Code,**

```
CommonUtils.decodedStringValue(request.getHeader("SEARCH_TEXT"));
```

Hope this helps.